# Regex no two consecutive characters are the same

Tags: regex

How do I write a regular expression where x is a string whose characters are either a, b, c but no two consecutive characters are the same

For example

abcacb is true

acbaac is false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`^(?!.*(.)\1)[abc]+$` works if you follow the original question exactly. However, this does *not* work/check multiple "words" of characters a/b/c, ie. "abc cba".

The way it works is it asserts that any character is not followed by itself by utilizing a capture group inside a lookahead and that the entire string consists only of characters "a", "b", or "c".

Answer (score 1):

Since the number of chars is limited, you can get away without a back reference in the look ahead:

```
^(?!.*(aa|bb|cc)[abc]*$
```

But I like tenub's answer better :)

Answer (score 0):

- using negative lookbehind: `^([abc]([abc](?<!(aa|bb|cc)))*)?$` [**TRY HERE**](https://regex101.com/r/SJYVFh/1)
- using negative lookahead: `^(((?!(aa|bb|cc))[abc])*[abc])?$` [**TRY HERE**](https://regex101.com/r/Cefxz5/1)

Prefer either (both do the same job but differently) if you are going to use this regex as a part of some bigger regex that you might be creating.
In short, this is reusable. Copy & paste and it will do its work without disturbing any regex that is present around it.

In my humble opinion, regexes provided in **@tenub** and **@Bohemian** are not reusable which can cause bugs.

**Note**: empty string (`""`) will pass these 2 regexes. If you don't want it to, remove `?` from regex.

Comment: remove `^` and `$` from regex before reusing this regex. `^` denotes the start of the string and `$` denotes the end of the string.